# Rust using same member variable name in new function argument

Tags: rust

Does the following code compile to something sensible?

```
impl MyType {

    pub fn new(my_data) -> Self {
        Self {
            my_data : my_data,
        }
    }

}
```

where `my_data` is a member of `MyType`:

```
struct MyType {

    my_data: i32, // whatever

}
```

In the constructor function `new` the name of the argument is the same as the member variable name of the type. Is this permitted, and does it compile with the expected behavior?

In C++ we have pretty much the same thing, however if there is ever a case where this causes ambiguity (it doesn't in constructors) then we can use `this->my_data`, where `this` is a pointer to the current object, similar to `self: Self` in Rust.

Comment: Your first example is not valid Rust. struct member assignment uses `:`, not `=`

Comment: For a property with the same name as the variable you can omit the "assignment" part, as in `Self { my_data }` suffices. Note that in Rust, unlike C++, properties do require the `self.` part to be accessible, as in later you can refer to `self.my_data` for a function with `self` as an argument.

Comment: In Rust, members of `self` are not implicitly brought into the namespace of methods. You must *always* refer to them like `self.my_data`.

Comment: why write my_data twice ? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fc62bd7ed749f1d37bd7e4c84851953f in rust we are civilized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a few edits, yes, [it compiles](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=struct+MyType+%7B%0A++++my_data%3A+i32%2C+%2F%2F+whatever%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl+MyType+%7B%0A++++pub+fn+new%28my_data%3A+i32%29+-%3E+Self+%7B%0A++++++++Self+%7B%0A++++++++++++my_data%3A+my_data%2C%0A++++++++%7D%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Apub+fn+main%28%29+%7B%0A++++let+v+%3D+MyType%3A%3Anew%2842%29%3B%0A++++println%21%28%22%7B%7D%22%2C+v.my_data%29%3B%0A%7D%0A). There is no ambiguity in the `new` function, as we are constructing `Self` (`MyType`) by defining each of its fields in a `key: value` fashion. You may find more information about it in the Rust Book, [Defining and Instantiating Structs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-01-defining-structs.html) chapter.

```rust
struct MyType {
    my_data: i32, // whatever
}

impl MyType {
    pub fn new(my_data: i32) -> Self {
        Self {
            my_data: my_data,
         // ^field   ^argument variable
        }
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let v = MyType::new(42);
    println!("{}", v.my_data); // 42
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I know it compiles, although I made a typo while copying it yesterday. Just wasn't sure if it should do what I expected in all cases.